# Detects when the computer does not have any COM serial port listed as a device

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need find some way to detect if the computer have or not any COM  port device connected.
The code show when some COM, is available, but nothing show when I disconnect the only one device I have use a COM port.
I check on windows device panel, no COM is there, and nothing happen.
Then I connect the device, and the code work ok and inform COM port found.
What I doing wrong?

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
string pattern = "COM";

foreach (string portnames in ports)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(portnames, pattern))
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("COM port found!");
    }    
    else
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("COM port not found!");
        //this not is working !
    }
}
```

---

Ok.
No idea why the else not work, but knowing the first part of code work ok, here I update the code and now work.
Thanks everybody to try to help!!

```
            existCOMport = false;


            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            string pattern = "COM";
            foreach (string portnames in ports)
            {
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(portnames, pattern) == true)
             {
                    existCOMport = true;
                 //START HANDSHAKE CODE
                }


             }

                if (existCOMport == false)
            {
             //INFORM, NOTHING TO DO, NO ANY COM PORTS DEVICE
            }
```

Comment: Is the device in question a "real" Serial-Port Device or are we talking USB? That might have an effect on possible answers.

Comment: In case of "real Serial Device" - does it properly support DSR (Data Set Ready) / CTS (Clear To Send) signaling?

Comment: It is pretty wonky code, as-is you only have to check for ports.Length > 0.  In practice you always really, really care that the *specific* port is available.  But sure, USB emulators are never not a problem.  Serial ports are not plug-and-play devices and the salaries of programmers that work on USB device drivers are supported by dirt-cheap hardware.  For one it is absolutely crucial that you always, always use the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon before disconnecting the device.

Comment: @HansPassant "are never not a problem" == "are always a problem" ? double negations make my head spin :)

Comment: @Akspa serial ports have no "connected" status. You can detect the state of various pins, but that's it. The other device doesn't even have to keep any of them raised all the time. Are you referring to a USB-to-serial adapter perhaps?

Comment: Perfect handshake is a work, yes it is, but i have all solved this night!
Thanks guys!

Comment: Guys, i have this fixed, my native language is spanish, I change the tittle to a proper tittle.

Comment: Thanks to everyone!!!

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should post the solution (if it hasn't been posted by someone else) as an *answer* and then (after the enforced delay) *accept* the answer. That's how SO works. You **should not** edit the answer into your question nor edit the title to say `SOLVED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SerialPort.GetPortNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) only return the ports that are available.

> Gets an array of serial port names for the current computer.

So really you want a check like this:

```
if(ports.Length > 0)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("COM port found!");
    //then maybe do a foreach ports here if needed
}
else
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("COM port not found!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help, anyway I fixed the code. 
Best regards!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not how the old serial ports work.
You can't detect if a cable is plugged in. You can however detect if one specific device (one of which you know how it communicates), is properly powered and connected, by opening the port and listen for expected data if it is an active device. 
Or by opening a connection and sending a known command to the device, which invokes a (known) response from the device.
(eg: a gps unit usually transmits data automatically each xxx time interval), and some devices only respond to specific commands.

When you know your device you can listen for, or invoke a command. And compare it with your suspected return data. Use a timeout to handle the case in which no serial device is connected to the COM port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I already scan all com ports, send a message, and wait for answer, all the handshake part is already implemented.
Just want implement some clean code without throw exception, in cases no any com port is there .
Thanks anyway for your reply and your time.

Comment: _"You can't detect if a cable is plugged in."_ - That's not the full story, though.

Comment: With this code no, of course!
The correct way to know if COM device is alive is start a handshake with the device.
I already have solved that part with other code.
But just want a simple code to detect all COM, real or virtual listed on the system, available or not, just all COM are listed.
I think my title is wrong. Sorry, my native language is spanish not english.
Anyway the code I update work now, and basically I can detect when no any port is there.

Comment: In the case there are no COM ports on the computer, your for each loop will never iterate. This is because SerialPort.GetPortNames() returns only the ports that are available on the computer. If there are no ports it returns an empty array with zero elements. (the function also only lists COM ports so it is not really necessary to match with the Regex for 'COM'). Got it, posted this just after your answer ;)